# MacOS: The Operation can't be completed because the disk is full

Tags: macos

You are copying a bunch of files, you know you have enough space on your SSD but suddenly you're getting the error below:

[image: Your Disk is Full]

[image: Other Volumes In Container]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason you got the error is there are other unmounted drives since they're unmounted they cannot be used. In my case, they appear under "Other Volumes in Container".

For you to resolve this, you'll need to go to Disk Utility (Command + Space > type Disk Utility). Navigate to View menu > Show All Drives. There you can delete those drives to free up space.

Comment: Be careful deleting things without knowing what they are. If there are other normal volumes, make sure they don't have anything you need on them before deleting them. You might also see some normally-hidden system volumes (including, but not limited to, "Preboot", "Recovery", and "VM") which you shouldn't delete.

Comment: I don't think you can actually delete those Prebook, Recovery, and VM volumes? You may not have access to that in the Disk Utility UI, yes, you can see it being on a disabled like.

Answer (score 0):

*Left side apple icon -> About This Mac -> Storage -> Manage*

Now, you can delete some data like applications, Bin, documents etc to free up storage.

Comment: As obvious as this answer is, is is surprisingly very helpful as there are options to clean xcode build chaches, indexes, etc which took up 40gb on my machine.

Comment: Or, you can just restart the computer - sometimes apps take lots of storage, which is cleaned up by restarting.